# Как на node.js спарсить данные с vk.com подгружаемые при скролле?

Tags: node.js, парсер, вконтакте, прокрутка, phantomjs

Добрейшего времени суток!

Впервые занимаюсь web scraping'ом. Мне необходимо получить полный список коротких имен сообществ (event) по выбранному городу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Имею следующий код, который выводит в консоль 40 результатов:

```
var website_url = "https://vk.com/search?c%5Bcity%5D=1&c%5Bcountry%5D=1&c%5Bsection%5D=communities&c%5Bskip_catalog%5D=1&c%5Btype%5D=3";

request({
uri: website_url,
method:'POST',
encoding:'binary'
}, function (error, response, html) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('.labeled.title').each(function(i, elem){
        var a = $(this).children();
        var url = a.attr('href');
        console.log(url);
        console.log(i);
    });
} else if (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
});
```

Как получить абсолютно все данные, а не только те 40, которые были подгружены при загрузке страницы? На сколько я понял, нужен "безголовый браузер"?

P.S. При скролле ВК отправляет POST запрос на адрес https://vk.com/al_search.php постоянно меняя параметр offset.

Спасибо! ;-)

Comment: А не проще воспользоваться api у vk?

Comment: @gil9red В методе groups.Search есть обязательный параметр 'q' (поисковое слово). В iOS приложении делал множество запросов со словами из массива var ABC = ["в","с","до","от","2017","по","на","за","для","фестиваль","день","уроки","встреча","отдых","МК"] ,но меня такое не устраивает, к тому же некоторые сообщества все равно пропускаются, решил сделать API, где все собираю, сортирую и в приложении получаю одним запросом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовал библиотеку Nightmare.

[Страница библиотеки на GitHub](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare)

```
nightmare.goto('https://vk.com/search?c%5Bcity%5D=1&c%5Bcountry%5D=1&c%5Bsection%5D=communities&c%5Bskip_catalog%5D=1&c%5Btype%5D=3')
.wait(2000)
.inject('js', './jquery_v1_10_2.js') // jQuery скачен и размещен локально
.wait(2000)
.scrollTo(999999999999999999999999999,0)
.wait(5000)
.evaluate(function () {
    var shortNames = [];
    $('.labeled.title a').each(function () {
        item = {}
        item['link'] = $(this).attr('href');
        $.trim(item['link']); // убрал лишние пробелы
        item['link'] = item['link'].replace('/',''); // убрал слеши
        item['link'] = item['link'].replace('event',''); // убрал слово event 
        shortNames.push(item) // массив с готовыми id
    })
    return shortNames
})
.end()
.then(function (result) {
    for (name in result) {
        console.log(result[name].link)
        console.log('\n')
    }
});
```

**2 вариант.**
Можно заменить scrollTo, на .inject('js', './scrollAnimate.js').

```
nightmare.goto('https://vk.com/search?c%5Bcity%5D=' + CitiesID[c] + '&c%5Bcountry%5D=1&c%5Bsection%5D=communities&c%5Bskip_catalog%5D=1&c%5Btype%5D=3')
    .wait(2000)
    .inject('js', './jquery_v1_10_2.js')
    .wait(3000)
    .inject('js', './scrollAnimate.js')
    .wait(15000)
    .evaluate(function () {...}
```

А в файле scrollAnimate.js записать следующий JS код:
(прокручивание до футера срабатывает только 1-2 раза, поэтому снова огромное значение)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
for(var i=0; i<11; i++) { // 11 циклов необходимо, чтобы прокрутить до футера страницу с 1000 групп
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 10000000000000000000000000000 }, 800);
    }, 1500); // timeout можно уменьшить или убрать, но я оставил, чтобы ajax-данные 100% загрузились
}
});
```

И при инициализации "ночного кошмара" указать объект со след. параметрами, чтобы можно было при тестировании посмотреть прямо в браузере  Electron, как вообще выполняется код.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true, dock: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

> На сколько я понял, нужен "безголовый браузер"?

Например Phantom.js, Selenium, но есть другой подход, имитация HTTP (AJAX) запросов, для их отслеживания и анализа нужен сниффер, такой как Fiddler, Wireshark, Charles, затем с помощью любого ЯП можно отправить такой запрос, этот вариант отличается лучшим быстродействием, но тяжелее обеспечить высокую точность, впрочем, VK не Mail.Ru, он "не гоняется за каждым ботом", есть только общие для всех правила вроде капчей и лимитов.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Не получилось связать Phantom.js и ноду, хотя после прочтения документации он мне понравился. Нашел аналогичную библиотеку для node.js - Nightmare.